# Android Room Select query returns null or empty strings even the database is not empty

Tags: android, android-room

I'm new to android and room. I'm trying to make a local db but I'm struggling at this point where the database is not empty as the image below proves. But when I try to select any data it returns an empty list or null values. Note that the insert query works fine.
[image]

Code:
Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "product_table")
@Parcelize
data class Product(

    @PrimaryKey
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id : String,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title : String,
    @SerializedName("price")
    val price : String,
    @SerializedName("category")
    val category : String,
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description : String,
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image : String,

    val color : String,
    val size : String
): Parcelable
```

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface CartDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product_table")
    fun get_all_carts(): LiveData<List<Product>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insert_item_to_cart(product: Product) : Long

    @Delete
    suspend fun delete_item_from_cart(product: Product)


    @Query("Delete FROM product_table")
    fun delete_all_cart()

}
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = [Product::class], version = 1)
abstract class ProductDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun productDao(): CartDao

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ProductDatabase? = null

        fun getDataseClient(context: Context) : ProductDatabase {

            if (INSTANCE != null) return INSTANCE!!

            synchronized(this) {

                INSTANCE = Room
                    .databaseBuilder(context, ProductDatabase::class.java, "product_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()

                return INSTANCE!!

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
class CartRepository {

    companion object {

        var productDatabase: ProductDatabase? = null

        var product: LiveData<Product>? = null

        fun initializeDB(context: Context) : ProductDatabase {
            return ProductDatabase.getDataseClient(context)
        }

        fun get_all_data(context: Context) : List<Product> {

            productDatabase = initializeDB(context)
            var temp_list = emptyList<Product>()

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                temp_list = productDatabase!!.productDao().get_all_carts()
            }
            return temp_list
        }

        fun get_first_item(context: Context, input_id : String) : Product {

            productDatabase = initializeDB(context)
            var temp_item : Product = Product("","","","","","","","")

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                temp_item = productDatabase!!.productDao().get_item(input_id)
            }
            return temp_item
        }



    }
}
```

View Model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CartFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val productDao : CartDao
) : ViewModel() {

    var products_list : MutableLiveData<List<Product>>

    init {
        products_list = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun get_all_products(context: Context) : List<Product>{

        return CartRepository.get_all_data(context)

    }
    fun get_first_item(context: Context, input_id : String) : Product{

        return CartRepository.get_first_item(context, input_id)

    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class CartFragment @Inject constructor(

) : Fragment(R.layout.cart_fragment_layout) {


    lateinit var cart_list : List<Product>

    val cart_adapter = CartRecyclerViewAdapter()

    val viewModel by activityViewModels<CartFragmentViewModel>()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        rv_cart.adapter = cart_adapter
        rv_cart.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(
            activity?.applicationContext,
            LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,
            false
        )
        rv_cart.setHasFixedSize(true)

        /*cart_list = viewModel.get_all_products(activity?.applicationContext!!)
        cart_adapter.submitList(
            cart_list
        )
        cart_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetched Data: {${cart_list.get(1).title}}")*/

        var p = viewModel.get_first_item(activity?.applicationContext!!, "1")
        cart_adapter.submitList(
            listOf(
                p
            )
        )
        cart_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        var s = p.title
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetched Data: {$s}")

        /*viewModel.get_first_item(activity?.applicationContext!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            cart_adapter.submitList(listOf(it))
            cart_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })*/

        //viewModel.get_first_item(activity?.applicationContext!!)
    }
}
```

There are many comments and logs in the `Fragment` Class for the sake of trying to figure what the problem is. I can't really know what is happening and when I use `LiveData` as return type of dao get functions the app crashes. Hope someone can help me out and thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your **CartRepository** methods.

```
 fun get_first_item(context: Context, input_id : String) : Product {

        productDatabase = initializeDB(context)
        var temp_item : Product = Product("","","","","","","","")

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            temp_item = productDatabase!!.productDao().get_item(input_id)
        }
        return temp_item
    }
```

In the above method, you are fetching an item in a background thread which means it goes into another thread and allows the return temp_item to always returns immediately, without blocking the code to wait for a result so that's why you are getting null and or empty list.

**Solution is** :

Make all database operation methods in **CartRepository** as suspended, see below:
*Note: I use an object instead of class*

```
object CartRepository {


    var productDatabase: ProductDatabase? = null


    fun initializeDB(context: Context) : ProductDatabase {
        return ProductDatabase.getDataseClient(context)
    }

   suspend fun get_all_data(context: Context) : List<Product> {

        productDatabase = initializeDB(context)
        
     return productDatabase!!.productDao().get_all_carts()
    }

  suspend fun get_first_item(context: Context, input_id : String) : Product {

        productDatabase = initializeDB(context)
        return productDatabase!!.productDao().get_item(input_id)
    }
```

}

And in your viewModel call this suspend function in **viewModelScope** like below:

```
@HiltViewModel
class CartFragmentViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val productDao : CartDao
) : ViewModel() {



 .....
       var productData = MutableLiveData<Product>()

fun get_first_item(context: Context, input_id: String) {

    viewModelScope.lauch(Dispatchers.IO){
        val data = CartRepository.get_first_item(context, input_id)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            productData.value = data
        }

    }

}
```

....

In your fragment call **get_first_item** first then observe you data productData and you can do the same things for other database operations also by following all steps.

*I hope this will help you if you dont understand any code just let me know in the comments and please ignore the typos*

Comment: Wow! You saved me so much time. Thanks. I thought ```CoroutineScope``` does the same thing as ```viewModelScope```. I'm a bit confused now but at least I know what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To use a LiveData with room, firstly, you should attach an observer to the live data.

So instead of returning the value of LiveData from the Repository methods, you should **return the Live Data object itself**,
And then observe that Livedata in your Viewmodel class.